# Viewing root access files/folders of android on windows

Tags: android, root, file-transfer

I'm trying to view the files and folders at root level on an android device using USB Debugging mode and windows. Is this possible? Phone is rooted.

I've downloaded a file explorer app which allows me to view it on the phone itself.

My main goal is to copy the mmssms.db from the phone.

Comment: Are you trying to write a desktop application? Or do you just want to see the files. Either way you can use ADB shell to browse the files

Comment: @dymmeh, I'm going to "attempt" to create a desktop based application. Cheers

Answer (score 12):

**Droid Explorer**
http://de.codeplex.com/releases/view/612392

**Window Apps:**
[image: Window]

**Explorer:**
[image: Explorer]

**SQLite Manager:**
[image: Sqlite]

Comment: It is insanely huge.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking long and hard for a solution to this problem and the best I found was a root FTP server on the phone that you connect to on Windows with an FTP client like FileZilla, on the same WiFi network of course.

The root FTP server app I ended up using is [FTP Droid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.ftpdroid&hl=en). I tried a lot of other FTP apps with bigger download numbers but none of them worked for me for whatever reason. So install this app and set a user with home as / or wherever you want.

**2021 EDIT**: FTP Droid isn't being updated and doesn't work on modern Android versions, now I use [primitive FTPd](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.primftpd) which is open source on Github

Then make note of the phone IP and connect with FileZilla and you should have access to the root of the phone. The biggest benefit I found is I can download entire folders and FTP will just queue it up and take care of it. So I downloaded all of my /data/data/ folder when I was looking for an app and could search on my PC. Very handy.

Comment: On Android device can be installed [`Termux`](https://github.com/termux), installed SSH server (`pkg install openssh-sftp-server`) and run by [`sshd`](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access). Then from PC it will be possible to connect to device by SFTP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Eclipse DDMS perspective to see connected devices and browse through files, you can also pull and push files to the device. You can also do a bunch of stuff using DDMS, this [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/ddms.html) explains a little bit more of DDMS uses.

EDIT:

If you just want to copy a database you can locate the database on eclipse DDMS file explorer, select it and then pull the database from the device to your computer.

Comment: Go to Window -> Show view -> Android -> File Explorer

Comment: @maxrasugido, Thanks for the input. My main goal is to have a GUI which allows the user to export the DB from the device to the desktop

Answer (score 0):

If you have android, you can install free app on phone (Wifi file Transfer) and enable ssl, port and other options for access and send data in both directions just start application and write in pc browser phone ip and port. enjoy!

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

**Obviously**, you'll need a rooted android device. Then set up an **FTP** server and transfer the files.